# MySQL CAST as DATE

Tags: mysql, sql, date, casting

I'm trying to understand what casting a value to the DATE type in MySQL does. Here are some things I have tried:

```
SELECT CAST('3' AS DATE);
-- null

SELECT CAST(3 AS DATE);
-- null

SELECT CAST('2014-07-01 19:00:01' AS DATE);
-- 2014-07-01

SELECT DATE('2014-07-01 19:00:01');
-- 2014-07-01

SELECT CAST('2014-07-01' AS DATE);
-- 2014-07-01

SELECT DATE('2014-07-01');
-- 2014-07-01

SELECT CAST('2014-07-50' AS DATE);
-- null

SELECT DATE('2014-07-50');
-- null

SELECT DATE(''), CAST('' AS DATE), DATE(0), CAST(0 AS DATE);
-- null, null, 0000-00-00, 0000-00-00
```

Everything I've tried seems to either convert it to `null` if it's invalid or return the date portion of the string if it's a valid date. I've even tried dates with slashes and other formats, same results.

What's the difference between using the [`DATE(expr)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function and the [`CAST(expr AS DATE)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)?

> `DATE(expr)`: Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression expr.
>
> `CAST(expr AS type)`: The `CAST()` function takes an expression of any type and produces a result value of a specified type, similar to `CONVERT()`

Similarly, the same question can be asked about times with `TIME(expr)` and `CAST(expr AS TIME)`.

Comment: I think this explains your null values: "If you convert a “zero” date string to a date, CONVERT() and CAST() return NULL and produce a warning when the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode is enabled." Check the warning with "SHOW WARNINGS;"
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: Furthermore: "MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'". You are probably looking for DATETIME. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

Comment: Regardless of whether I have times or not, I want to know the difference between using `CAST(expr AS DATE)` and `DATE(expr)`, and I suppose the same can be asked for time: `TIME(expr)` vs `CAST(expr AS TIME)`. Also I've added my results for the zero date.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question you asked, but could I suggest using unix timestamps instead of dates?  The datatype of your column would be a bigint.  You take that timestamp (a number) and can convert it into readable strings with date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $yourTimestamp);  More formatting options [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: @Lakey Nowhere in this question did I tag or mention PHP and I'm not sure why everyone is assuming that I want a date and time format. **My question applies regardless of whether I'm working with dates, times, or dates and times.**

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Hey rink, firstly, it's not a crazy assumption to assume you're using PHP or python, since those are *by far* the most common languages used with MySQL.  Secondly, my comment was just intended to be a helpful suggestion.  If it's not helpful, feel free to ignore it -- That's why I wrote it in the form of a *comment* instead of an *answer*.  Thirdly, I have developed several MySQL driven applications, a few used by tens of thousands of users ...and I've **never once** needed to use a date/time-related MySQL function, nor a date/time datatype.  There are better options.

Comment: @Lakey Sorry, my comment wasn't intended to be offensive, it's just that I'm not looking for *how to parse dates* but rather the functionality of MySQL regarding the functions that I mentioned. Parsing dates is relatively straightforward whether I'm using PHP, Java, Node.js, or MySQL's own `DATE_FORMAT()` function.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Checking the source code of MySQL 5.6 `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` calls to the same internal function  `Item_date_typecast`, `DATE()` calls to  `Item_date_typecast` too.

In conclusion **there is no difference** between `DATE(expr)` function and the `CAST(expr AS DATE)`.

Refs:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.6/sql/sql_yacc.yy

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.6/sql/item_create.cc