# how to just get date without getting time when you retrieve data from database in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, mysql

[click here for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8cUb.png)
This picture shows time as well with date. how to just get date
my database stored the datatype of just date. still when i retrieve it from database in my controller/ model it gets time as well.how to just get date and not get 00:00:00 beside it

```
model:-
    public DataTable getallusers()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string strConString = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=test,Integrated Security=TRUE";
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(strConString))
          {
            conn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;" +"pwd='password' ;database=test";
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select e.id, e.name, r.rolename, e.dob, e.email, 
            e.address,e.contact, e.gender from erp_user e inner join roles_table r on e.roleid = r.id",conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
          }

        return dt;
    }
    controller:-
    public ActionResult Index()
     {
       CRUDModel model = new CRUDModel();
       DataTable dt = model.getallusers();
       return View("Home", dt);
     }
    view:-
    @using System.Data
    @using MySql.Data.MySqlClient
    @model System.Data.DataTable
   <html>
    <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
       <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form method="post" name="Display">
         <div class="wrapper">
              <h3>Home</h3>
        </div>
        @{
          if (Model.Rows.Count > 0)
          {
            <div class="wrapper">
                <table border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                DOB
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    @foreach (DataRow dr in Model.Rows)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@dr["dob"].ToString()  </td>               
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
                    <br />
                }}
</form>
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Pkq.png
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL CAST as DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165882/mysql-cast-as-date)

Comment: Shouldnt how to display the data be decided in the View?

Comment: No actually the date is to be fetched from database..hardcoded date is not required.

Comment: well the date is to be extracted from query...view is just displaying the data in tabular form.

Answer (score 1):

In your view convert the date to the format you want using the ToString() method

```
@Model.dob.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

For formatting options see the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: please can u help me with the code of view, i have posted it above.

Comment: This answer has information enough so you can incorporate it in your view