# MySQL date() returning time with the date, only date expected

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, casting

I used the `date` function of mysql like below.
But it returns the date and the time instead of just the date. Why is that?

```
select if(1, date(now()), time(now())) , if(1, date(now()), 'a'), if(1, time(now()), 'b') from dual;
```

[image: return]

Comment: This looks to be an artifact with the SQL client tool you are using.

Comment: What do you mean by "the date + time"? What's the expected output?

Comment: Not sure why that happens. Casting to `date` also doesn't resolve the issue, but casting to `time` only gives back time. Could use `substr(date(now()), 1, 10)` ... `cast` and `date` are the same per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165882/mysql-cast-as-date so I guess that behavior makes sense.

Comment: @NicoHaase Should just be a date, no time.

Comment: you can use CURDATE() function for current date, without time

Comment: @Pioter88 That doesn't resolve the issue, time is still returned in OP's use case. `select if(1, CURDATE(), time(now()))`

Answer (score 0):

The datatype produced bytthe first `IF()` is a datetime, see:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test select if(1, date(now()), time(now())) , if(1, date(now()), 'a'), if(1, time(now()), 'b') from dual;
SHOW CREATE TABLE test;
```

(also  in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/R43Lljpu) )

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if) is not very clear about it:

> **IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)**
>
> - If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 IS NOT NULL), IF() returns
>   expr2. Otherwise, it returns expr3.
>
> If only one of expr2 or expr3 is explicitly NULL, the result type of
> the IF() function is the type of the non-NULL expression.
>
> The default return type of IF() (which may matter when it is stored
> into a temporary table) is calculated as follows:
>
> - If expr2 or expr3 produce a string, the result is a string.
> - If expr2 and expr3 are both strings, the result is case-sensitive if
>   either string is case-sensitive.
> - If expr2 or expr3 produce a floating-point value, the result is a
>   floating-point value.
> - If expr2 or expr3 produce an integer, the result is an integer.

But details about the return type when using DATE, or TIME, are missing....

**EDIT**:

I forgot to mention that this makes sense because a column in a result set an only have one data type.

This can be seen when doing:

```sql
create table test 
  select 
     if(1,date(now()),time(now())) A,
     if(0,date(now()),time(now())) B,
     if(1,1,'c') C,
     if(0,1,'d') D,
     if(1,date(now()),'E') E
  ;
show create table test;
```

Which gives:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `A` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `B` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `C` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `D` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `E` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Note that column E is a varchar(10)

Comment: I think the answer is in the `CASE` section of the documentation you linked. `...For a mix of temporal types, the result is DATETIME.` Not sure why that is the case for `select case when 1 then CURDATE() end as returnvalue
union
select case when 0 then time(now()) end as returnvalue` still though. It seems like first cases return should be a `date`, not mixed.

Comment: I added an extra piece of info about data types of the column, which can only be one, and not sometimes a date() and at other times a time().  MySQL is choosing a datatype which matches both the true and false situation of the IF().